# c# ssl request - certifcate validation

Tags: c#, ssl, https, nginx, x509certificate

I'm adding a self-signed X509 Certificate to an HTTPS request.

```
request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(@"key.pfx", ""));
```

It is talking to nginx, with:

```
 ssl_verify_client on;
```

As it is self signed I get an error on the certificate signing chain.  So I tell c# to ignore it. (The lambda is executed and true is returned)

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                                (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

However, I then get the following error from nginx.

```
400 Bad Request
No required SSL certificate was sent
nginx/1.0.5
```

Can anyone explain why this might be happening? Or how I can track down why?
*My current thinking: The certificate is getting removed from the http client because it is self-signed?*

Also: some diagnostic output from c#

```
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate'
System.Net Information: 0 : [5516] SecureChannel#31534420 - Remote certificate has errors:
System.Net Information: 0 : [5516] SecureChannel#31534420 -     A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

System.Net Information: 0 : [5516] SecureChannel#31534420 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user.
```

Any help most welcome! Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: to me it seems to make that work you need to disable the SSL verification on nginx...

Comment: The point is that I want nginx verification.  I only want clients with certificates to have access to the server.

Comment: that won't work... I don't know whether nginx has some config option for allowing self-signed certs - if it has and that is what you want then you are better off asking this on serverfault.com . Otherwise turn it of in nginx and do the verification of the client certs on the server in code...

Comment: nginx has an ssl_client_certificate property, which is set to the CA certificate that signed my client key.  What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: `ssl_verify_depth 1;` was needed...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the client's certificate on the server and configure the server to trust it. I have no experience with nginx, so I can't help you with the how, but you need to get the client certificate's into the server's trusted certificate store.